# ListView doesn't show items when updated from a fucntion

Tags: java, android, listview

I am using Android Studio, I have an activity with a list, when I add items to the list after filling a textbox and clicking a button the items show, but when I try to add items to the list from an SQL query the list does not show the items.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent d = getIntent();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_group);
  String choosengroup = d.getStringExtra("chosen");

    groupn = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.gname);
    soldiern = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.soldiername);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
    final Button savebutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.savegroup);
    final Button addbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addsoldier);
    final DatabaseHelper db;
    db = new DatabaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
    setListAdapter(adapter);

    if(!choosengroup.equals("")){
        groupn.setText(choosengroup);
        list=getAllsoldiers(choosengroup,db);
        // Log.d("list",list.toString());
        onContentChanged ();

    }

    savebutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            db.createGroup(new Groups(groupn.getText().toString())); //Creates a group in Groups table
            // Creates a new table for the specific group
            db.getWritableDatabase().execSQL(" CREATE TABLE `Group_"+groupn.getText().toString()+"` (`id`   INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,`name`   TEXT,`ghours`   INTEGER DEFAULT "+'"'+"0"+'"'+",`ahours`INTEGER DEFAULT "+'"'+"0"+'"'+", `khours`   INTEGER DEFAULT "+'"'+"0"+'"'+");");
            for (String name: list) {
              //  Log.d("names:",name.toString());
                db.getWritableDatabase().execSQL("INSERT INTO `Group_"+groupn.getText().toString()+"` (name) VALUES('"+name+"');");
            }
            Intent act2 = new Intent(view.getContext(),ChooseGroup.class);
            startActivity(act2);
        }


    });

    addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

          // soldier.add(new Soldiers(soldiern.getText().toString()));
            list.add(soldiern.getText().toString());
            soldiern.setText("");
            //setListAdapter(adapter);
            Log.d("list",list.toString());
            onContentChanged ();
        }

    });
```

The addbutton.setOnClickListener add items and they are shown on the list.

But this :

```
 if(!choosengroup.equals("")){
        groupn.setText(choosengroup);
        list=getAllsoldiers(choosengroup,db);
        // Log.d("list",list.toString());
        onContentChanged ();

         }
```

Does not show the items on the listview.
Any idea why?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post the body of getAllsoldiers(choosengroup,db)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
list.addAll(getAllsoldiers(choosengroup,db));
```

instead of

```
list=getAllsoldiers(choosengroup,db);
```

My thinking is that the assignment:

```
list=getAllsoldiers(choosengroup,db);
```

changes the value of the reference held in list from the original list to a new reference, and the adapter is still using the reference to the original list.

ie when you created the adapter, you passed in the value of the reference to the original list
when you did the assignment, you just changed the value of reference stored in list, but the adapter is still holding the pointer to the original list

using addAll() will add the items to the original list which is still being referenced by your adapter.